# Database for schema-less JSON file

Tags: json, mongodb, database-design, database-schema

I have a fairly large (~1GB) valid JSON file that doesn't follow any particular schema/format and is frequently updated. I'm looking for a database system that is:

- Fairly robust and mature
- Able to incrementally import this JSON file (in an `upsert` fashion)
- Able to perform queries on arrays and objects at arbitrary locations inside the object (select, sort and the likes)

MongoDB would've been a great option but as far as I can tell, importing this file using `mongoimport` requires several modifications to the JSON file (to meet "jsonArray" mode's requirements) that I prefer to avoid.

Comment: And I want to have my cake and eat it too...

Comment: @fdreger why is that?

Comment: I am not sure there are any database systems designed for coping with your use case. MongoDB would likely be a good fit for you since you are already using a JSON data model, and any kind of storage engine would require you to refactor your data. Can you give a better idea of how your JSON file is structured / what is in it?

Comment: @3rf so my JSON file is huge and it has a few large arrays in it that can be translated to MongoDB collections, as well as many more arbitrary branches. the solution we came up with is a NodeJS script that sort of pull-parses the huge file and spits out those collections to be consumed by MongoDB, but doesn't do anything for those branches yet. what I had in mind was a DBMS that automatically handles this, basically a more powerful / customizable `mongoimport`.

Comment: Unfortunately there aren't any management systems meant to help you break down and import data with such an unstructured schema, at least any that I can think of. This sort of problem of breaking down such a non-generalizable use case is a great example of an application where a scripting language is the way to go :)